# CAP Theorem - satify consistency by always erroring on read

Tags: database, database-design, logic, computer-science, cap-theorem

The [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem) and one of my instructors say

> Consistency: Every read receives the most recent write or an error.

I have learned we can only satisfy two of them at all-time, but, seriously, wouldn't the "or an error" part mean we could satisfy the other two first, and then design the software to throw errors for all read operations? Then we have satisfied all three of them for all-time.

Comment: Is "or an error" intended to mean "otherwise an error"?

Comment: I don't think that makes a difference? My understanding is that "Otherwise" is the same as "or" and simply servers as a disjunctive clause.

Comment: Natural language or can mean inclusive or mean exclusive. ("servers as a disjunctive clause" is not clear.) Also otherwise <> or. Normally otherwise would imply that there is an error only if there isn't a most recent write to return. PS Formal definitions can often clearly be satisfied by trivial/degenerate cases, and that might be the case here. Then "quality of implementation" matters. PS Put what is needed to ask in your post. Parphrase/quote with credit from other sources. Especially don't rely on Wikipedia to not change. Also it is generally a poor source. Find an authoritative source.

Comment: I see. That's helpful! My instructor probably copied from Wikipedia. One of the sources quoted is behind a paywall, so I haven't been able to find the actual source. PS sorry typo again... I meant "serves"

Comment: My understanding of what you are suggesting as an alternative is that the only case for not having a most recent write is when there have been no writes, and "or an error" is meant for this case.

Comment: I don't know what the consequences of a particular interpretation for "or" would be or what likely interpretations were meant because it's not in the question & not at a link in the question that is to a permanent & accessible resource. PS Observe that a very early & very important term "Consistency" (the C in CAP) in the linked article is not defined in the article in the CAP sense nor does the Wikipedia article linked where the word first appears mention CAP. So how do you expect to understand CAP from the article? It just gives some vague impressions, it doesn't define & isn't a tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the definition for "A". In order to satisfy "A", the response should not be an error. If you throw an error every time, how can the system satisfy "A" which stands for Availability? You only satisfy "C" and "P".

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20theoretical%20computer%20science%2C%20the,Availability).

> **Availability** Every request receives a (non-error) response, without
> the guarantee that it contains the most recent write.